# nginx refused to apply style from site

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-config

Completely new to `nginx` and need some guidance. I am supporting a new site that the business named one thing during development and then purchased a different hostname. and the application of css is being refused. This is a live production site so it's accessible @ https://mh.lhfs.com. The test server (different machine) and the local dev server are working properly so I'm assuming it's server related. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the configuration file. The prior developer loved copy and paste. I cleaned up the Content-Security-Policy section but it didn't resolve the issue.

```
    server {
    listen 80;
   # listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/vhosts/lhfs.com/webpages/manufactured.lhfs.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name mh.lhfs.com;
    #server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

   #return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    server_tokens off;
    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:; frame-src img-src 'self' font-src 'self' default-src 'self' object-src 'none' https://*.typekit.net https://mh.lhfs.com https://lhfs.com https://mortgage.lhfs.com https://cdn.lhfs.com https://lhfs.com https://lhfscdn.com https://seal-goldengate.bbb.org http://seal-goldengate.bbb.org https://*.mylivechat.com https://mylivechat.com https://code.jquery.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com http://ajax.googleapis.com http://www.google-analytics.com http://www.google.com http://ajax.googleapis.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://maps.googleapis.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://themes.googleusercontent.com https://tautt.zendesk.com https://assets.zendesk.com https://connect.facebook.net https://s-static.ak.facebook.com https://www.facebook.com https://s-static.ak.facebook.com http://0.gravatar.com https://www.gstatic.com http://1.gravatat.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://maps.gstatic.com https://csi.gstatic.com";

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";

   #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

   access_log  /var/www/vhosts/lhfs.com/webpages/manufactured.lhfs.com/logs/access.log;
   error_log /var/www/vhosts/lhfs.com/webpages/manufactured.lhfs.com/logs/error.log;

   error_page 404 /404.html;
   error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
   location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   }

    location ~ \.php$ {
       root /var/www/vhosts/lhfs.com/webpages/manufactured.lhfs.com;         
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

    ssl_certificate /var/www/vhosts/system/sslcerts/cert-lhfscom/lhfs.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/www/vhosts/system/sslcerts/cert-lhfscom/lhfscom_frommt.key;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /var/www/vhosts/system/sslcerts/cert-lhfscom/lhfs.com.chained.crt;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    access_log  /var/www/vhosts/lhfs.com/webpages/manufactured.lhfs.com/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/vhosts/lhfs.com/webpages/manufactured.lhfs.com/logs/error.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
       root /var/www/vhosts/lhfs.com/webpages/manufactured.lhfs.com;         
       try_files $uri =404;
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

}
```

UPDATE 1:

I tried a few different things I saw in other posts but they didn't help

- I removed the type='text/css'from the style sheet declaration in the index.php file but I had the same results.
- I checked the mime.types config file and the types were defined.
- I checked the nginx.config and verified that that mime.types config was being included.

I might add this is not the only site on this server that delivers these errors. All of them do to some extent. one difference is that this site has the css on the site path. The other sites don't have a problem displaying the css. The developer decided to reference css style sheets from another servers WordPress site. (Don't ask! Everyone, want's all of their sites to break if one goes offline don't they? One reason he's not around any longer.)

UPDATE 2:
I decided to comment out the CSP section and try again. The site loaded successfully. I will leave this off for a while I Investigate further. It appears to be configured properly but apparently, it is not. Please post if you have any ideas as to what would be causing the problem in the section.

Comment: There has to be a glitch. The HTML code that's failing to load the CSS and the relevant parts of your nginx.con and sites-available which you provided along with your question are not visible for some reason

Comment: @JavierLarroulet I just added the configuration file.

Comment: What is https://mh.lhfs.com/include/css/main.css supposed to resolve to?

Comment: the root path of /var/www/vhosts/lhfs.com/webpages/manufactured.lhfs.com/include/css/main.css and that file does exist in that path